# How to draw bottom half of a 3D tube with C# 

Tags: c#, 3d, gdi+, draw

I create storage (Picture A) with DrawStorage(). To fill the storage I use FillWater(). I wanted to fill storage with water according to the level of 0-100% (empty-full) such as picture C, but current output is generated from FillWater() like the Picture B. How to fill the storage to look like the Picture C ? The difficulty is how to fill the storage so that it looks like 3D (Picture C)

Sorry if my english isn't good. I hope help of you who are experts, Thank you.

[image: output]

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
        Graphics g = pe.Graphics;
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        this.DrawBar(g, this.ForeColor);
    }


    private void DrawBar(Graphics g, Color foreColor)
    {
        bool outLine = this._outLineColor != Color.Transparent;
        Rectangle bound = this.ClientRectangle;
        bound.Inflate(-20, -20);

        DrawStorage(g, bound, new Size(4, 10), Color.FromArgb(this.Alpha, foreColor), this.OutLineColor, outLine);

        if (this.Value > this.Minimum && this.Value <= this.Maximum)
        {
            float barValue = bound.Height * ((this.Value - this.Minimum) / (this.Maximum - this.Minimum));
            RectangleF valueBound = RectangleF.FromLTRB(bound.Left, bound.Bottom - barValue, bound.Right, bound.Bottom);

            FillWater(g, valueBound, new Size(4, 10), Color.FromArgb(this.Alpha, this.BarColor), this.OutLineColor, outLine);

            if (this._showValue && valueBound.Height > 20)
            {
                g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
                format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                g.DrawString(this._value.ToString("F2"), this.Font, Brushes.Black, valueBound, format);
                format.Dispose();
            }
        } 
    }


    public static void DrawStorage(Graphics g, RectangleF front, SizeF depth, Color fillColor, Color borderColor, bool outLine)
    {
        if (front.Width <= 0 || front.Height <= 0)
            return;

        // Make Back Side Area
        RectangleF aback = front;

        // Make Depth
        aback.X += depth.Width;
        aback.Y -= depth.Height;

        // Create Top and Bottom Plane. 
        RectangleF leftPlane;
        RectangleF rightPlane;

        // Create Graphics Object
        GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();

        rightPlane = new RectangleF(front.Width, front.Y, front.X, front.Height);
        leftPlane = new RectangleF(front.X, front.Y, front.X, front.Height);

        // Brush
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(fillColor);

        // Border Pen
        Pen borderPen = new Pen(borderColor);

        /***************
         *   LEFT    *
         * ************/
        // Make GP On Bottom
        gp.AddEllipse(leftPlane);

        // Get Bottom color
        brush.Color = GetSideColor(fillColor, WallSide.Left);

        // Fill Bottom Plane
        g.FillPath(brush, gp);

        // Shadow of the Body
        FillCylinderShadow(g, front, gp, false);

        // Check Draw Border
        if (outLine)
            g.DrawPath(borderPen, gp);

        gp.Reset();
        gp.AddArc(rightPlane, 270, 180);
        gp.AddArc(leftPlane, 90, -180);
        gp.CloseFigure();

        /***************
         *     Body    *
         * ************/
        // Color For Body is real Fill Color.
        brush.Color = fillColor;

        // Fill Body
        g.FillPath(brush, gp);

        // Shadow of the Body
        FillCylinderShadow(g, front, gp, true);

        // Check Draw Border
        if (outLine)
            g.DrawPath(borderPen, gp);

        /***************
         *     RIGHT     *
         * ************/
        gp.Reset();
        gp.AddEllipse(rightPlane);

        // Get Bottom color
        brush.Color = GetSideColor(fillColor, WallSide.Back);

        // Fill Top Plane
        g.FillPath(brush, gp);

        // Shadow of the Body
        FillCylinderShadow(g, front, gp, true);

        //Check Draw Border
        if (outLine)
            g.DrawPath(borderPen, gp);

        // Dispose
        gp.Dispose();
        brush.Dispose();
        borderPen.Dispose();
    }


    public static void FillWater(Graphics g, RectangleF front, SizeF depth, Color fillColor, Color borderColor, bool outLine)
    {
        if (front.Width <= 0 || front.Height <= 0)
            return;

        // Make Back Side Area
        RectangleF aback = front;

        // Make Depth
        aback.X += depth.Width;
        aback.Y -= depth.Height;

        // Create Top and Bottom Plane. 
        RectangleF leftPlane;
        RectangleF rightPlane;

        // Create Graphics Object
        GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();

        rightPlane = new RectangleF(front.Width, front.Y, front.X, front.Height);
        leftPlane = new RectangleF(front.X, front.Y, front.X, front.Height);

        // Brush
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(fillColor);

        // Border Pen
        Pen borderPen = new Pen(borderColor);

        /***************
         *   LEFT    *
         * ************/
        // Make GP On Bottom
        gp.AddEllipse(leftPlane);

        // Get Bottom color
        brush.Color = GetSideColor(fillColor, WallSide.Left);

        // Fill Bottom Plane
        g.FillPath(brush, gp);

        // Shadow of the Body
        FillCylinderShadow(g, front, gp, false);

        // Check Draw Border
        if (outLine)
            g.DrawPath(borderPen, gp);

        gp.Reset();
        gp.AddArc(rightPlane, 270, 180);
        gp.AddArc(leftPlane, 90, -180);
        gp.CloseFigure();

        /***************
         *     Body    *
         * ************/
        // Color For Body is real Fill Color.
        brush.Color = fillColor;

        // Fill Body
        g.FillPath(brush, gp);

        // Shadow of the Body
        FillCylinderShadow(g, front, gp, true);

        // Check Draw Border
        if (outLine)
            g.DrawPath(borderPen, gp);

        /***************
         *     RIGHT     *
         * ************/
        gp.Reset();
        gp.AddEllipse(rightPlane);

        // Get Bottom color
        brush.Color = GetSideColor(fillColor, WallSide.Back);

        // Fill Top Plane
        g.FillPath(brush, gp);

        // Shadow of the Body
        FillCylinderShadow(g, front, gp, true);

        //Check Draw Border
        if (outLine)
            g.DrawPath(borderPen, gp);

        // Dispose
        gp.Dispose();
        brush.Dispose();
        borderPen.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: You could always take the easy way and rotate your cylinder 90 degrees and fill it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some limited success in creating the 3D effect using draw order and clipping.  The code below generally works, but has some issues when the fill is near 0% or 100%... I think that can be fixed.

[image: 3D cylinder]

```
/// <summary>
/// Calculate X coordinate on an ellipse
/// </summary>
/// <param name="width">Ellipse width</param>
/// <param name="height">Ellipse height</param>
/// <param name="y">Y ranging from 0 to height</param>
/// <returns>X relative to the center of the ellipse</returns>
/// 
static float EllipseCalculateX( float width, float height, float y )
{
    if ( y < 0 || y > height )
    {
        return 0;
    }

    y = y - ( height / 2f );
    var a = width / 2f;
    var b = height / 2f;

    var x = ( a * Math.Sqrt( ( b * b ) - ( y * y ) ) ) / b;

    return (float)x;
}

protected override void OnPaint( PaintEventArgs e )
{
    var g = e.Graphics;

    var percent_full = PercentFull;


    // length, width, and depth of the storage in pixels
    //
    var storage_length = 140f;
    var storage_height = 80f;            
    var storage_depth  = 15f;


    var start = new PointF( 80, 50 );

    var cylinder = new RectangleF( start.X, start.Y, storage_length, storage_height );
    var left_cap = new RectangleF( cylinder.Left - ( storage_depth / 2f ), cylinder.Top, storage_depth, storage_height );
    var right_cap = new RectangleF( cylinder.Right - ( storage_depth / 2f ), cylinder.Top, storage_depth, storage_height );


    // relative x,y of the fill level on the "near" (front) side of the storage
    //
    var fill_near_y = storage_height * ( percent_full / 100f );
    var fill_near_x = EllipseCalculateX( storage_depth, storage_height, fill_near_y );

    // relative x,y of the fill level on the "far" (back) side of the storage
    // y is offset slightly for the 3D effect
    //
    var fill_far_y = storage_height * ( percent_full / 100f ) + ( storage_depth / 2f );
    var fill_far_x = EllipseCalculateX( storage_depth, storage_height, fill_far_y );


    // absolute x,y of the fill level on the left side (near and far)
    //
    var fill_left_far = new PointF( cylinder.Left - fill_far_x, cylinder.Bottom - fill_far_y );
    var fill_left_near = new PointF( cylinder.Left + fill_near_x, cylinder.Bottom - fill_near_y );

    // absolute x,y of the fill level on the right side (near and far)
    //
    var fill_right_far = new PointF( cylinder.Right - fill_far_x, cylinder.Bottom - fill_far_y );
    var fill_right_near = new PointF( cylinder.Right + fill_near_x, cylinder.Bottom - fill_near_y );

    // calculate the slope between the near and far levels
    //
    var slope = ( fill_left_far.Y - fill_left_near.Y ) / ( fill_left_far.X - fill_left_near.X + 0.001f );

    // build a clip path to be used in filling the left cap; its top is angled to match the 3D effect
    // the first two points in the path have to be extended outside of the cap ellipse, or the fill will look wrong above 50% fill
    //
    var left_clip = new GraphicsPath();
    left_clip.AddPolygon( new PointF[] {
        new PointF( left_cap.Left, fill_left_far.Y - ( slope * ( fill_left_far.X - left_cap.Left ) ) ), 
        new PointF( left_cap.Right, fill_left_near.Y + ( slope * ( left_cap.Right - fill_left_near.X ) ) ), 
        new PointF( left_cap.Right, left_cap.Bottom ), 
        new PointF( left_cap.Left, left_cap.Bottom ),
    } );

    // same for right cap
    // 
    var right_clip = new GraphicsPath();
    right_clip.AddPolygon( new PointF[] {
        new PointF( right_cap.Left, fill_right_far.Y - ( slope * ( fill_right_far.X - right_cap.Left ) ) ), 
        new PointF( right_cap.Right, fill_right_near.Y + ( slope * ( right_cap.Right - fill_right_near.X ) )),
        new PointF( right_cap.Right, left_cap.Bottom ), 
        new PointF( right_cap.Left, right_cap.Bottom ),
    } );

    var outline = new Pen( Color.Black, 2f ) { LineJoin = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineJoin.Bevel };

    // outline the top and bottom of the storage
    //
    g.DrawLine( outline, cylinder.Left, cylinder.Top, cylinder.Right, cylinder.Top );
    g.DrawLine( outline, cylinder.Left, cylinder.Bottom, cylinder.Right, cylinder.Bottom );


    // outline the right cap
    //
    g.DrawEllipse( outline, right_cap );


    // outline and fill the right side
    //
    g.SetClip( right_clip );
    g.DrawEllipse( outline, right_cap );
    g.FillEllipse( Brushes.Orange, right_cap );
    g.ResetClip();


    // fill in the center area
    //
    g.SetClip( RectangleF.FromLTRB( cylinder.Left, fill_left_near.Y, cylinder.Right, cylinder.Bottom ) );
    g.FillRectangle( Brushes.Orange, cylinder );
    g.ResetClip();


    // fill left side
    //
    g.SetClip( left_clip );
    g.FillEllipse( Brushes.Yellow, left_cap );
    g.ResetClip();


    // outline and fill the surface
    //
    var surface = new[] { fill_left_near, fill_left_far, fill_right_far, fill_right_near, fill_left_near };
    g.DrawPolygon( outline, surface );
    g.FillPolygon( Brushes.Yellow, surface );


    // outline the left cap
    //
    g.DrawEllipse( outline, left_cap );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Um well actually your 3d drawing is in fact a collage of 2d shapes, which is why you can "see" inside both ends of the pipe for instance. You can probably get there this way mind. If you draw the chord at x% on both ends of the pipe (sort out the right hand end, it should have the same angle as the left)
Then join them up so you have a plane representing the surface of the water, that should give you enough points to outline the filled part of the pipe and a couple of Fill commands once you have the filled are outlined should do the job.

Comment: I can add the arc on the left side of the cylinder, the problem is how to calculate minor axis(width of the water) if mayor axis(water level) is known? Changes are not linear, because ellipse-shaped surface.

Comment: You have an angle of projection to give the 3d effect draw a line up from the bottom of the pipe (vertical radius lower half) then at your projection angle draw left and right until it intercepts the boundary of the ellipse. Then fill, I think. Hard to say, I'd have done a 3d model of the pipe and content then projected it. Harddeer in some ways but makes the issues you are running into trivial.